# How can I make all of the subplots in sns.FacetGrid fit?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe `df` like so:

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz6OJ.png)

There are 6 countries in this dataframe. I am trying to create a facet grid in order to visualize pairwise correlations of GDP between each country using `sns.regplot`. Since I have 6 countries, there will be `6 ** 2 = 36` pairwise combinations. Currently I am getting `UserWarning: Tight layout not applied. tight_layout cannot make axes width small enough to accommodate all axes decorations self.fig.tight_layout(*args, **kwargs)`. Here is part of the output:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMFtx.png)

How can I make this fit?
Here is my code:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, row='Country', col='Country')
g.map(sns.regplot, data=df, x='GDP', y='GDP')
```

Comment: Try specifying `col_wrap`, `height`, and `ascpect` in your FaceGrid.  Might allow you to get fewer graphs per row and make each graph a little larger while you're at it.  https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html

Comment: You might want to use a [pairplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pairplot.html) here, although it will require pivoting your dataframe (`df.pivot(columns="Country", values="GDP")`). With the `FacetGrid`, you'll probably avoid the problem by setting `margin_titles=True`.

Comment: @mwaskom setting `margin_titles=True` resolved the issue. However, only the diagonal plots are displaying any data. Any thoughts to why this is?

Comment: @RobProner If your row and column variables are the same, then the diagonal axes are the only ones that could have data. It's impossible for an observation to have both `Country == 'Chile'` and `Country == 'China'`, for example.